# How to mount a Windows shared drive on OS X given a Windows user like this: myserver@mydomain.com

Tags: windows, macos, bash, shell, terminal-services

I have a script in OS X which is something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "SMB://myuser:mypwd@myhost/sharedfolder"
    end try
end tell
```

It works fine,  but now there is an additional share with the credentials like so:

```
myuser1@mydomain.com
```

If I add the following line to the script, it fails:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "SMB://myuser:mypwd@myhost/sharedfolder"
        mount volume "SMB://myuser:myuser1@mydomain.com@myhost/sharedfolder1"
    end try
end tell
```

Can anybody tell how I should configure my script to get it working?

Comment: What scripting language? If you want an answer you must specify where the problem is found. Perhaps this is obvious to Mac owners (AppleScript?), but to me It seems like relevant info to include.

Answer (score 0):

One of these solutions *might* work (no access to a Mac at the moment):

1. Escape the first `@`

   ```
   mount volume "SMB://myuser:myuser1\@mydomain.com@myhost/sharedfolder1"`
   ```
2. Play with the quotes. Try

   ```
   mount volume "SMB://myuser:'myuser1@mydomain.com'@myhost/sharedfolder1"
   ```

   or

   ```
   mount volume 'SMB://myuser:"myuser1@mydomain.com"@myhost/sharedfolder1'
   ```

Are you sure you need to specify the domain? Don't see why of the first mount succeeds. Unless the actual *username* is `myuser1@mydomain.com` which, unless I am missing something obvious, seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of encoding `@` in URLs is using **URL-encoding**, which results in `%40` (`@` is ASCII 40h) – so use `myuser%40mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain access to the SMB share by specifying your Windows login and the machines IP address like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=winuser,password=winpass //192.168.0.105/myshare /mnt/share
```